# Robustly segmenting a csv file containing noisy data

Tags: command-line, grep, csv, split

Say I have a csv file with these columns:

```
timestamp,cpu,memory
```

An example of the shape of the actual data would be this chart:

[image: cpu/mem csv data as chart]

Having the data visualized in this way, it's easy for the human eye to make out where any of the 4 cpu intensive activities start and end.

What would be an easy way, using standard unix cmd line tools, ideally not resorting to `R` or `octave` etc, to **"grep" only the 8 lines of the file that denote the onset and end of these 4 activities**, based on the "cpu" column?

Obviously this is somewhat fuzzy, and there is noise in the data, but any solution that gives me 8 lines that are somewhere close to onset/end is appreciated.

A short excerpt of the csv file, showing only the first of those 4 bursts of activity:

```
10:44:21.310,0,53567488
10:44:22.310,1.56257,53575680
10:44:23.326,0,53854208
10:44:24.325,34.3761,57405440
10:44:25.325,73.43985,61747200
10:44:26.325,3.1251,69459968
10:44:27.325,0,69459968
10:44:28.325,0,69459968
10:44:29.325,65.6271,74756096
10:44:30.325,53.1267,77783040
...
10:50:56.450,35.93865,142700544
10:50:57.450,10.93785,142897152
10:50:58.450,1.56255,142897152
10:50:59.450,0,142897152
10:51:00.450,0,142897152
10:51:01.450,0,142897152
```

Ideally, this would result in the following 2 lines.

```
10:44:24.325,34.3761,57405440
10:50:58.450,1.56255,142897152
```

However, as there is no cpu activity for a couple of seconds between `10:44:26.325` and `10:44:28.325`, I don't expect the answer to be that smart and do something akin to 'smoothing' the data. So if a csv snippet like the above would e.g. yield the following 4 lines, that would suffice.

```
10:44:24.325,34.3761,57405440
10:44:26.325,3.1251,69459968
10:44:29.325,65.6271,74756096
10:50:58.450,1.56255,142897152
```

Comment: Could you provide csv data here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do this is with `awk`. You can set a threshold to get the first line the threshold is hit and last line it falls below. Something like this might work:

```
awk -F, -vthreshold_up=20 -vthreshold_down=10 'BEGIN {
                          cur = "gt";
                        } 
                        {
                          if (cur == "gt" && $2 > threshold_up) {
                            print;
                            cur = "lt";
                          } else if (cur = "lt" && $2 < threshold_down) {
                            print;
                            cur = "gt";
                          }
                        }' file.csv
```

Comment: Won't that print _all_ lines that are above or below the threshold? I am assuming the OP only wants the start/end of each major change.

Comment: @terdon No, it won't print all those lines, because the variable `cur` stores the current state and if you check the if/else statements, you should see that it works.

Comment: this worked great (after splitting `threshold` into `threshold_up` and `threshold_down`)! will accept, unless something more ingenious shows up

Comment: @EugeneBeresovksy ah, yes indeed. Nice one jordanm!

Comment: @jordanm - welcome to 10k, I just pushed you over 8-)

Comment: @slm thanks! 9.9k-10k was agonizing because I was so close :).

Answer (score 2):

Extending jordanm's approach, I was able to build something surprisingly robust, without having to resort to statistics. The script got a little bit longer unfortunately, but this is finished, and now I can use it as often as I need it, with only figuring out the right parameters.

I tested it on a dozen of actual data files, some as messy as this one:

[image: chart of messy cpu and memory csv]

The trick here is the use of the `MIN_DURATION` variable, which helps ignoring temporary spikes and slumps of up to the specified number of lines.

**Usage:**

```
grep-begin-end FIELD_SEPARATOR FIELD_INDEX THRESHOLD_UP THRESHOLD_DOWN MIN_DURATION ...
```

**Example:**

```
grep-begin-end , 2 30 4 5 file.csv
```

**grep-begin-end**

```
FIELD_SEPARATOR=$1
FIELD_INDEX=$2
THRESHOLD_UP=$3
THRESHOLD_DOWN=$4
MIN_DURATION=$5
shift 5
awk -F$FIELD_SEPARATOR -vthreshold_up=$THRESHOLD_UP -vthreshold_down=$THRESHOLD_DOWN 'BEGIN {
    cur = "gt";
}
{
    val = $'$FIELD_INDEX';
    # strip of double quotes and convert to number
    if (substr(val, 1, 1) == "\"") { val = 0 + substr(val, 2, length(val) - 3); } else { val = 0 + val; }
    buf = "";
    if (cur == "gt")
    {
        if (val >= threshold_up)
        {
            if (buf == "")
                buf = $0;
            if (duration >= '$MIN_DURATION')
            {
                print buf;
                cur = "lt";
                duration = 0;
                buf = "";
            }
            else
            {
                duration++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            duration = 0;
        }
    }
    else if (cur == "lt")
    {
        if (val <= threshold_down)
        {
            if (buf == "")
                buf = $0;
            if (duration >= '$MIN_DURATION')
            {
                print buf;
                cur = "gt";
                duration = 0;
                buf = "";
            }
            else
            {
                duration++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            duration = 0;
        }
    }
}' "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking that you could just write a little script that prints if the current value differs from the last one by more than N. Since your data seem to be very discrete and the changes happen from one measurement to the next, that should work.

Something like

```
awk -F, -v thr=100 '{if ($2-last>thr || last-$2>thr){print;} last=$2;}' foo.csv
```

Comment: Your prose (N times greater/smaller than previous) doesn't match your code (difference greater/smaller than `thr`). That said, if what you mean by *N times greater/smaller* treats an increase from 1 to 2 the same as a jump from 50 to 100, then I don't think it would do the job very well.

Comment: @EugeneBeresovksy no, I meant what I wrote in `awk` not in the prose, thanks for pointing it out, answer edited. I'm just thinking you can specify a threshold `thr` and if the value changes more than `thr` between consecutive measurements, print. A very naive approach that will also print tiny spikes as your (much better) one will not.